# PHP Dotenv causing wordpress configuration to run twice

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, composer-php, phpdotenv

I have a relatively complex laravel project, within it I have a wordpress installation for a blog on the side which is installed with composer.

In my `wp-config.php` I use an include to a file in my config directory called `application.php` (for organisation purposes). I have various cases of `define('XXX', 'config stuff');` and similar in the file. When 'config stuff' is hard coded the site works perfectly, but recently I'm trying to use dotenv installed by composer to pull in values from my .env with getenv()

```
require_once(LARAVEL_PATH . '/vendor/autoload.php');
$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(APP_ROOT_DIR);
$dotenv->load();
```

When I `var_dump` my `getenv('example_env_constant')` it gives me the correct values absolutely fine. So I went about setting these throughout my application.php file.

But now when I load up the site I get a large number of

```
Notice: Constant XXX_XXXX_XXX already defined in /path/to/application.php on line X
```

One for every single `define('XXX', value);`

And also a

```
Cannot modify header information
```

On testing I've found that my `wp-config.php` file is being run once. But somehow my `application.php` is being run twice. The 1st run is from my include call in `wp-config.php` as it should be. The 2nd run which is triggering the errors is happening within `wp-settings.php` on line 326

```
do_action( 'plugins_loaded' );
```

I have no idea how this is happening.

If I remove the dotenv code from `application.php` and instead put it directly into my `wp-config.php` the behaviour is exactly the same, with `wp-config.php` running once and `application.php` running twice.

Now if I remove `application.php` and put all of my code into `wp-config.php` as wp config is traditionally done. Then I get the exact same issue again and it references the deleted file... this of course indicates a cache issue at this point although I don't think cache is the cause of the original issue. Running a cache flush using the wp cli doesn't work as it actually manages to hit the same errors from `application.php` when flushing. Never mind that caching is disabled in the first place anyway. This isn't a browser cache issue here either as a new incognito chrome instance and hard refreshing makes no difference.

This is a long read so sorry about that, I hope I was clear enough. I'm quite confused as to how this is happening and any help or tips for debugging this would be great. Maybe I've missed something very obvious as it appears that using dotenv for my wp config thoroughly breaks everything in ways that I've never seen before. Worst comes to worst I'll go back to hardcoding the wp-config file

Update:

I was mistake about deleting the application.php file not stopping the related bugs. It stops the require bugs but I get others instead. If I just delete the contents of application.php then I have no difference.

Something is majorly wrong, if anyone simply has any debugging advice it would be highly appreciated

Files:

- public/help-advice/[wp-config.php](https://pastebin.com/THqLwziq)
- config/[application.php](https://pastebin.com/WpaHTFJH)
- wordpress installation is in public/help-advice/wp
- non composer generated wp files are in public/help-advice/app or
  public/help-advice

**Pasted code if you can't use pastebin:**

*This is the config.php*

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
 * copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * MySQL settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

 /*
  * Caching
  */
define('WP_CACHE', true);
define('LARAVEL_PATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..'); // Make sure this is pointed to same server

require_once(LARAVEL_PATH . '/vendor/autoload.php');
require_once(LARAVEL_PATH . '/config/application.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

*This is the application.php*

```
<?php

//This file pulls in data for WP and is included in the wp-config.php file within help-advice

/*
 * Base paths
 */
define('APP_ROOT_DIR', dirname(__DIR__));

// $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(APP_ROOT_DIR);
// $dotenv->load();
// this one above works but causes this file to run twice causing errors, the one below errors
// if (file_exists(APP_ROOT_DIR . '/.env')) {
//     Dotenv\Dotenv::load(APP_ROOT_DIR);
// }

define('APP_PUBLIC_DIR', APP_ROOT_DIR . '/public/help-advice');
define('APP_STORAGE_DIR', APP_ROOT_DIR . '/storage');
define('APP_LOG_DIR', APP_STORAGE_DIR . '/logs');


// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'redacted');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'redacted');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'redacted');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         'redacted');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'redacted');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'redacted');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'redacted');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'redacted');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'redacted');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'redacted');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'redacted');


/*
 * Debugging/errors
 */
define('APP_DEBUG', (boolean) getenv('APP_DEBUG'));
// Always log errors
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', APP_LOG_DIR . '/wp_debug.log');
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', APP_DEBUG);
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', APP_DEBUG);
/*
 * URLs
 */
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/help-advice/wp');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/help-advice');
/*
 * Custom Content Directory (/public/help-advice/app)
 */
define('CONTENT_DIR', '/app');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', APP_PUBLIC_DIR . CONTENT_DIR);
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', WP_HOME . CONTENT_DIR);


//google analytics
define('GA_PROPERTY_ID',getenv('GA_PROPERTY_ID'));
/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/../public/help-advice/wp/');
```

Comment: Do you have any third-party plugins enabled in your WordPress installation? I can't quite see how it would happen, but my instinct tells me that the first thing to try would be disabling third-party plugins.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to see some more of your actual code, for example your wp-config.php file (or at least the minimum required to reproduce the problem, with passwords suitably redacted.)

Comment: Hi, my only 3rd party plugin is 'WordPress Laravel Bootstrap' which I will try disabling to see if it helps, although I do need it. And I'll update my post with pastebin links to the mentioned files @MattGibson

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid I can't see your files (my company blocks access to pastebin) so I can't be much more help myself, but perhaps others can step in.

Comment: I'll put them into here then so you can read them. Also I tried disabling the plugin, unfortunately the result is a white page as parts of the views are generated from laravel, this only works with the plugin.

Comment: @MattGibson another update, don't know how I didn't notice this before. But if I simply don't include the code `$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(APP_ROOT_DIR);
$dotenv->load();` then it still runs twice, the first time it fails to fetch any env variables so it fails if I make it dependent on them but somehow the 2nd run it is successful in fetching the variables, very confusing, I'll keep digging

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it runs twice or is triggered by the do_action( 'plugins_loaded' ); on the 2nd run.

Since this is a fairly unique build/situation and I don't expect this to be easily fixed or for more than a couple of people to ever need this. So instead of continuing to tear my hair out I added a check to every definition in my application.php to see if it already existed, if so don't re-define. example: `if (!defined('WP_DEBUG')) {define('WP_DEBUG', true);}`

I was also getting errors from advanced-cache.php missing as a result of the dotenv being added to application.php, no idea why, especially since I never installed or had anything to do with advanced-cache. So I simply disabled this `define('WP_CACHE', false);`